e-Shop (shopify) header randomly started showing the drawer menu
I have just started (yesterday) using Shopify, and I created an eShop.
Last night, everything I worked on ended up wonderfully, but today, I saw a random drawer menu showing up in the header.
Screenshot attached.
Now, I have a choice for a menu in header setup. Whether I use Mega Menu or Dropdown Menu, I still have a drawer menu besides the chosen one, but if I choose drawer menu, I only see a drawer menu.
This pretty much screws my entire header.
Did anyone else have the same problem? Can someone help me work this out?
Note: I tried other browser (Edge), and it doesn't show the drawer menu. Also, The private (incognito) window in Opera doesn't too.
Also, I cleared all the cookies, cache, and even flushed Opera's dns socket. nothing worked.
The template I'm using is called Trade.


Anyone having even a remotely clever idea on how to solve it?
I'm here to give any clarifications, if needed...
